# UWP Windows Iot Core VoIP Support

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, voip, windows-iot-core-10

I would like to find out if Win10 IoT Core supports VoIP?
If it does, where can I get reference as I googled and can't find any info or reference.
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't down vote my question with no reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, voip/sip is currently not supported under windows iot core. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VoIP) is a VoIP UWP sample, but i don't think it can work on Windows IoT Core. Some codec is not supported on Windows IoT Core, you can refer to [Supported codecs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs).

Comment: I have tried the voip UWP sample.. it doesn't work on iot core... is there any possible way to work around to use windows iot core as an IP based intercom? Thank you.

Comment: It seems that somebody was successfully able to get reSIProcate and the basicClient example program to run on my Raspberry Pi 2 under Windows 10 IOT Core!  Very few changes were required to the stack in order to get it to compile as an ARM target.